# Showing that the set is disconnected

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I need to prove directly from the definition that $$(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2, x^2-y^2=1$$ is disconnected.

Can someone please give a methodological answer? I cannot handle this type of problems

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you try to sketch the set?

Comment: I need a formal proof @Sheol

Comment: From your sketch, write down the two components of your set. You only have to show that there exist $U$ and $V$ open and disjoint such that $U\cup V$ is your set.

Answer (score 3):

The hyperbola is the union of two disjoint closed sets
$$ \left\{(x, y)\ | \ x = \sqrt{1 + y^2}\right\} \cup \left\{(x, y)\ | \ x = -\sqrt{1 + y^2}\right\}
$$
It is easy to see that no $(x, y)$ satisfies the two conditions simultaneously.

Comment: $\mathbb R^2$ is the union of two disjoint sets also. You need to say more.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to see that there is no point on your curve where $x=0$. There is at least one point with $x<0$, namely $(-1,0)$, and at least one point with $x>0$, namely $(1,0)$.

Therefore the sets $\{(x,y)\mid x<0\}$ and $\{(x,y)\mid x>0\}$ are disjoint open sets whose union contains your set and for which each intersection with your set is non-empty. Therefore, by the most common definition of "connected," your set is not connected.